# How do you pass in complex objects into a brightcove plugin?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, brightcove

I am creating a Brightcove plugin.  The documentation implies that if you need pass in data to your plugin that you need to do that by attaching flashvars to the swf url. (example: myPlugin.swf?myVar=foo&yourVar=bar )

Is there another way to pass in vars?  I want to be able to pass in an array of objects, each which contain objects as their own into my plugin.

If there isn't another way, how do I do that with a flash var string?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to use the BEML paradigm to pass in various XML style nodes and then parse those into classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BEML is only to style your player and to attach modules/plugins.

If you download their [GoogleAnalytics](http://files.brightcove.com/google-flash-sample/GoogleAnalytics.zip) example.

You can build your plugin off that, and also this is how I was able to use Flashvars with that particular plugin:

```
myVar = this._bcStage.root.loaderInfo.parameters.flashVar;
```

I needed the `_bcStage` in order to get access to the HTML.